# How to get the recency value?

Tags: r, datetime, database-design

I want to get the recent value.

```
 ID month_0   month_01 month_02 month_03 
 1        0         10        0        0
 2       10          0        0        0
 3       10          0       35        0
 4        0          0       15        0
 5        0          0        0       35
```

My data is as above,
I want to get the recency value.

```
recency
id 1 -> 1
id 2 -> 0
id 3 -> 0
id 4 -> 2
id 5 -> 3
```

Please help me how I can get the recency value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way.  Not sure if there's a standard way, but this uses `rle` (run length encoding) which seems logical for this problem.

Assuming `dat` is your data

```
> apply(dat[-1], 1, function(x){ 
      with(rle(x), ifelse(!values[1], lengths[1], 0)) })
# [1] 1 0 0 2 3
```

Answer (score 4):

```
df <- data.frame(month0 = c(0,10,10,0,0), month1 = c(10,0,0,0,0), month2 = c(0,0,35,15,0), month3 = c(0,0,0,0,35))

apply(df, 1, function(x) Position(function(y) y > 0, x)) - 1
# [1] 1 0 0 2 3
```

Comment: `Position` is new to me.  Nice.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
 dat <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, month_0 = c(0L, 10L, 10L, 0L, 0L), month_01 = c(10L, 
 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), month_02 = c(0L, 0L, 35L, 15L, 0L), month_03 = c(0L, 
 0L, 0L, 0L, 35L)), .Names = c("ID", "month_0", "month_01", "month_02", 
 "month_03"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Create an index by first creating a logical transverse matrix of values>0 in the `month` columns `t(!!dat[,-1])` and multiply it with the column number of dat[,-1]

```
 indx <- t((!!dat[,-1]))*seq_len(ncol(dat[,-1]))
```

If I understand correctly, you need the first non-zero value for each ID.  ID3 has values >0 in `month_0` and `month_02`.  So, select `month_0`.

Create a row-column index and select only the first value per each column by `duplicated`

```
 indx1 <- which(!!indx,arr.ind=T)
 indx[indx1[!duplicated(indx1[,2]),]]-1
 #[1] 1 0 0 2 3
```

#### Speed comparison

```
  set.seed(148)
  m1 <- matrix(sample(c(0, 10,25,35,15),1e5*10,replace=T),nrow=1e5)
  d1 <- data.frame(ID=1:1e5, m1)

 f1 <- function(dat) {
 indx <- t(!!dat[,-1])*seq_len(ncol(dat[,-1]))
 indx1 <- which(!!indx, arr.ind=T)
 indx[indx1[!duplicated(indx1[,2]),]]-1
 }

f2 <- function(dat){
apply(dat[-1], 1, function(x){ 
with(rle(x), ifelse(!values[1], lengths[1], 0)) })
 }

 f3 <- function(dat){
 apply(dat[-1], 1, function(x) Position(function(y) y > 0, x)) - 1
 }

system.time(r1 <- f1(d1))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.550   0.004   0.555 

system.time(r2 <- f2(d1))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  7.870   0.000   7.851

system.time(r3 <- f3(d1))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.531   0.000   0.530 

identical(r1,r3)
#[1] TRUE
identical(r1,r2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: @Richard Scriven.  Edited the code.  Hope it works now.

Comment: Saw that...deleted my previous comment. :)